# Inequality with absolute expressions!

Tags: inequality

My problem as follows: 
I have $2$ set of numbers: $X = {x_1, x_2, ..., x_n}; Y = {y_1, y_2, ..., y_n}$. $x^*$ is average of set $X, y^*$ is average of set $Y$. The relationship between $X$ and $Y$ as follows:
$d(x*,X) \geq d(y^*, Y)$ -- where $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ (Manhattan distance)
$r$ is an added number to $X$ and $Y$ which satisfies: $d(r,X)=d(r,Y)$.
I need to prove $d(r,x^*)\leq d(r,y^*)$. But for a few weeks I have tried but I have not found any idea for proving this statement.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is $d(a, S)$ when $a$ is a number and $S$ is a set of numbers?

Comment: d(x*,X)=|x*-x1|+|x*-x2|+...+|x*-xn|

Comment: Consider $X=\{0,3\}$, $Y=\{-2,1\}$ and $r=0$. Then, the conditions on $X$, $Y$ and $r$ are met but $\frac32=d(r,x^*)>d(r,y^*)=\frac12$.